# Azure AD - Why can't I validate JWT token issued by Azure AD for my Web API? Getting "IDX10516: Signature validation failed" error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have a Web API that is protected by Azure AD. I am able to get access token for the Web API from Azure AD and use it successfully.

What I want to do is validate the token before performing any operation using that token so that I can give meaningful error messages to the user in case there's something wrong with the token. For example, some of the things I would like to tell user are:

1. Whether or not the token has expired?
2. Whether or not the token is acquired for correct audience?
3. Whether or not the token issuer is valid?

However I am not able to do so because regardless of whether the token is valid or invalid, I am constantly getting the following error message:

```
IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'System.String'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'. Valid Lifetime: 'System.Boolean'. Valid Issuer: 'System.Boolean'
```

I am successfully able to parse the token at [`https://jwt.io`](https://jwt.io).

Under the "Header" section there, I see the following:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "qDm8HXaLQBeSIvYXzMt8PQ_ADFt",//obfuscated
  "kid": "qDm8HXaLQBeSIvYXzMt8PQ_ADFt"//obfuscated
}
```

Also, I get `Signature Verified` message as well as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Here's the code I wrote:

```
string authorizationToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImt...";
try
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    };
    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authorizationToken, tokenValidationParameters, out _);//Exception comes on this line.
}
catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException exception)
{
    //Do something with the token expired exception
}
catch (SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException exception)
{
    //Do something with invalid audience exception
}
catch (Exception exception) //Code always lands in this exception block
{
    //Token is invalid because of some other reason
}
```

As I said above, my code is always landing in the last exception block regardless of whether the token is valid or not.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? What is needed to successfully validate the token?

Any insights into this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To validate the token, you need to specify the keys used by the identity provider (Azure AD) to sign the token:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = "<my token>";
            var tenantid = "<my azure ad  tenant id>";

            // => use to retrieve the keys used by AAD to sign the token
            var openidConfigManaged = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
                new HttpDocumentRetriever());
            var config = await openidConfigManaged.GetConfigurationAsync();

            var parameteres = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireAudience = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                // The Audience should be the requested resource => client_id and or resource identifier.
                // Refer to the "aud" claim in the token
                ValidAudiences = new[] { "<my client id or resource identitifer>" },
                // The issuer is the identity provider
                // Refer to the "iss" claim in the token
                ValidIssuers = new[] { $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/" }, 
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var claimPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, parameteres, out _);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas! 2 Follow up questions: 1) Can I safely assume that endpoint to get the open id configuration will always be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`? and 2) Can I safely assume that the valid issuer endpoint will always be `https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/`?

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you could point me to Microsoft documentation regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, yes your assumption are corrects.
For the open-id configuration endpoint you can refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document

Comment: For the issuer, you can check this doc as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: Thank you Thomas! Really appreciate your help regarding this. I do have some other doubts but I will ask them in a separate question.

Comment: Is your web api deployed as a webapp ? azure webapp also provide out of the box token validation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad.

Comment: net core also provides easiest way to configure azure ad auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

Comment: Thank you for these links. Much appreciated. Let me go through them. "_Naive_" me is thinking that I have to implement everything by myself; hoping to prove myself wrong :D.