# authentication and authorization with azure AD and python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I have two apps both registered on Azure AD:

-APP_1: a web app that runs in flask with SSO through Azure AD

```
tenant_id = "tenant_id_of_APP_1_and_APP_2"
client_id_app_1 = "app_1"
client_secret_app_1 = "secret_app_1"
```

-APP_2: another app that makes requests to the first app:

```
tenant_id = "tenant_id_of_APP_1_and_APP_2"
client_id_app_2 = "app_2"
client_secret_app_2 = "secret_app_2"
```

the endpoints on the APP_1 are restricted. When the user reaches the web app through the browser he is automatically requested to login, and after he is identified it can navigate any endpoint he has access to otherwise he gets PermissionError.

Now I want to give access to some endpoints to the APP_2, I can get an access_token from azure in this way (I think I'm going something wrong because when I request a token I should specify that is for APP_1, but i cannot find the argument that specifies it):

```
import requests
# Authenticate and get an access token
auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id_of_APP_1_and_APP_2}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id_app_2,
    'client_secret': client_secret_app_2,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
}
response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data).json()
access_token = response['access_token']
```

and then I can make the request to the protected API:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
}

x = requests.post("https://localhost:5000/test_api", headers=headers)
response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/test_api", headers=headers)
```

What should I do the server (APP_1) when I get such request? I should validate the access_token to verify the user but I cannot decode it with jwt because I keep getting invalid signature:

```
token = request.headers.get("Authorization").removeprefix("Bearer ")
public_key = get_public_key(token)
decoded = jwt.decode(
    token,
    public_key,
    verify=True,
    algorithms=["RS256"],
    audience=[client_id_app_1],
)
```

is there a better way to just send the access_token to azure for validation?

EDIT:

So I changed the code in this way:
on APP_2:

```
server_client_id = server_app_config.CLIENT_ID
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id_app_2, client_credential=client_secret_app_2, authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id_of_APP_1_and_APP_2}")
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[f"{client_id_app_1}/.default"])
access_token = result["access_token"]
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=payload)
```

on APP_1 I validate the token in this way:

```
token = request.headers.get("Authorization").removeprefix("Bearer ")
public_key = get_public_key(token)
decoded = jwt.decode(
    token,
    public_key,
    verify=True,
    algorithms=['RS256'],
    audience=[client_id_app_1],
)
```

Is this how the workflow should be?

Answer (score 0):

If you validate access token generated with **Microsoft Graph** scope, you will get "Invalid Signature" error like below as it not meant for application.

[image]

To resolve the error, you must use app-specific endpoint in scope while fetching token like `api://client_app_ID/.default`

> Note that, client credentials flow works with `Application` type
> permissions. If you are using client credentials flow to get tokens,
> you need to add **App roles** in Server App instead of exposing an
> API.

I registered one Server App and created few **App roles** in it like below:

[image]

Now, I registered one Client App and added above **App roles** in it like this:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to added App roles like below:

[image]

Now I ran below python code to get access token by changing **scope** parameter:

```py
import requests
# Authenticate and get an access token

tenant_id = "3f5c7a77-062d-426c-858xxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id_app_1 = "6d00f9c7-caaa-46d5-abxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_id_app_2 = "a3bebc65-2ba6-4fxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret_app_2 = "er48xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id_app_2,
    'client_secret': client_secret_app_2,
    'scope': 'api://client_id_app_1/.default'
}
response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data).json()
token = response['access_token']
print(token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded above access token by pasting it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), I got **`roles`** claim with permissions and **signature verified** successfully like below:

[image]

If you added scopes in **Expose an API** tab instead of adding App roles, then you need to use Delegated flows like authorization code flow, username password flow etc... to get access token that works with **Delegated** permissions.

**Reference:**

[jwt -  The signature verification is is failing - Stack Overflow by **Rukmini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009655/using-an-azure-ad-tenant-id-and-a-valid-token-issued-for-a-app-registration/76013867#76013867)