# Signature validation of my Azure access-token, Private-key?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token

Hello I want to know how to get the keys to verify the access token. I got the x5c from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantid}}/discovery/keys?appid={{app-id}}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenantid%7D%7D/discovery/keys?appid=%7B%7Bapp-id%7D%7D)

but if i put this key in jwt-decode function its failing. Do i need to do some processing on this key. Its a public key, do i need to know the private key to validate the signature or only public key is enough.

Can you please tell me some basic algo to validate the access_token.

Comment: You only need the public key to verify the signature. Can you show the code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Signature validation of my Azure access token, Private-key?

I agree with Junnas's comment you need a public key to verify the signature with an Azure access token.

You can use the below code to decode the access token with the public key using the **`PyJwt`** library.

**Code:**

```
import requests
import jwt
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import json

tenant_id = 'xxxx'
client_id = 'xxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxx'

token_endpoint = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
data = {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "client_id": f"{client_id}",  
      "client_secret": f"{client_secret}",  
      "scope": "api://your-client-id/.default"
    }
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data)
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
print(access_token)

response1 = requests.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/fb134080-e4d2-45f4-9562-f3a0c218f3b0/discovery/keys")
keys = response1.json()['keys']

token_headers = jwt.get_unverified_header(response.json()['access_token'])
token_alg = token_headers['alg']
token_kid = token_headers['kid']
public_key = None
for key in keys:
     if key['kid'] == token_kid:
         public_key = key 


rsa_pem_key = jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(public_key))
rsa_pem_key_bytes = rsa_pem_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM, 
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
) 


decoded_token = jwt.decode(
    response.json()['access_token'], 
    key=rsa_pem_key_bytes,
    verify=True,
    options={"verify_signature": True},
    algorithms=['RS256'],
    audience="api://client_id",
    issuer="https://sts.windows.net/tenant_id/"
)
s = json.dumps(decoded_token)
q = json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=2)
print(q)
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "aud": "api://xxxxx",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxx",
  "iat": 169028xxx,
  "nbf": 1690284xxx,
  "exp": 1690371xxx,
  "aio": "E2ZgYFDetxxxxxvq/ydjjk/BwA=",
  "appid": "d8xxxxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx,
  "oid": "dxxxxx",
  "rh": "xxxxx",
  "roles": [
    "tread.all"
  ],
  "sub": "dxxxxxx5",
  "tid": "fxxx",
  "uti": "wJxxxxxA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

[image]

**Note:** If you are using MS Graph API scopes **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** the results JWT would contain a "nonce" in the JWT Header and is not meant to be validated. Except you own API scopes.

**Reference:**

[jwt - Using an Azure AD tenant ID - and a valid token issued for a 'app registration'. The signature verification is is failing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009655/using-an-azure-ad-tenant-id-and-a-valid-token-issued-for-a-app-registration/76013867#76013867) by rukmini.

Comment: I have a doubt. I build a single page application with Azure AD integrated. Since the application is RBACed, I call my backend APIs with the ID token in Authorization header rather than the access token since ID token contains the roles of the user. But is this good practice? Can you please help me with the right way?

Answer (score 0):

**It took me more than a day to realize this, and I hope it can be helpful for you.**

I had the same issue a few days ago.

I was attempting to set up SSO using App registration.

I attempted to verify the accessToken from the response I received after exchanging it with a code from the callback URL.

But ultimately, it turns out that I should be validating the idToken which is intended for me, while the accessToken is intended for Microsoft Graph and does not require validation from our side.

So, check what you are verifying and make sure you know what you want to verify.