OAuth2AuthorizedClient access token have bad aud
I have an angular application packaged with spring boot who act like a bff.
I have another spring boot application for the api rest
When angular app go to home url, connection is done via bff.
@GetMapping(value = { "", "/", "/home" })
    public String index(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient() OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {  

    ...
    //OAuth2AuthenticationToken have idToken in the principal object
    log.warn(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());

    //call with grant type, client secret, client id and scope to graphApi
    //url [CLIENT_ID of the API app registration]/.default
    ...
    
}

In this bff app, i have use
aad.tenant=https://acme.onmicrosoft.com
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=     

aad.msGraphEndpointHost=https://graph.microsoft.com/
aad.appScope=https://graph.microsoft.com/
aad.accessTokenUri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=${aad.msGraphEndpointHost}User.Read.All
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.redirect-uri-template=
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.post-logout-redirect-uri=

In my api application, i have theses both properties
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=...
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.app-id-uri=...

So user go to home page, azure popup to enter user password after the bff endpoint is called and OAuth2AuthorizedClient  OAuth2AuthenticationToken object are feeded
Bff is used actually only for the security part. Angular call directly the api backend with the token took via graphApi. In the backend i would like to have an info to identify the user
I don't understand why the access token in OAuth2AuthorizedClient object can't be used.
Access token of this object have many information about the user.

When i try to use it to call api backend, i get

Vary:
Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An
error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT
rejected: Invalid signature",
error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1""

Do i need to specifiy something to use this access token in my api backend (maybe it use wrong algo?
In my api backend in my security class I have
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurityty
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        return configuration;
                    }))
                    .csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable().headers().xssProtection().and()
                    .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/actuator/**").permitAll().and()
                    .apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
                    .and().authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
       return http.build();
        
    }
}

In Azure ad api permission

Edit
OAuth2AuthorizedClient token have this info
"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/14a485d4-754c-4912-b891-f9cd98c49032/",
Token took when a call is made to url [CLIENT_ID of the API app registration]/.default
have theses info
"aud": "https://acme.onmicrosoft.com/9a452e9f-a9ba-412e-9efc-213c3bcaac0c",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/14a485d4-754c-4912-b891-f9cd98c49032/",
So why aud of OAuth2AuthorizedClient is bad?

Your question is very unclear, your BFF should authenticate with an issuer that in turn creates the token. You have to set in the issuer what signing algorithm you want to use. HS256 (hamc with sha256) is a symmetric keyed hashing algorithm, while RS256 (RSA with sha256) is an asymetric key algorithm. RS256/RS512 is what is recommended to use, because then you have public keys in all services and the issuer has the one and only private key. I dont know what your azure settings are but you need to check them

Also you should never hand out JWTs to browsers, but i assume that you are already aware of that.

only rs256 seem supported but if you go to ms page and copy paste any of the both token there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/access-tokens and paste it to jwt.io, there is a signature error if hs256 is not selected

i copy pasted both the tokens posted on that page into jwt io and both of them are rs256 so i have no idea what you are talking about

there are rs256, but if you check at the bottom of the page they said invalid signature

bottom of what page? be more specific, if you mean JWT io its because if you look at the decoded section on the right and at the bottom there is a box named verify signature the signature is invalid since you have not pasted in the public/private keys there that are used to verify the signature. Well im leaving this conversation, since this is not leading anywhere

The invalid signature error occurs if you are trying to validate the access token with aud as "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", as Microsoft Graph tokens are not meant to be validated

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009655/using-an-azure-ad-tenant-id-and-a-valid-token-issued-for-a-app-registration/76013867#76013867

so it's probably an error in the spring config because spring don't take the right aud. Spring don't seem to take aad.appScope

Yes make sure that the code takes aad.appScope that is https://acme.onmicrosoft.com/9a452e9f-a9ba-412e-9efc-213c3bcaac0c and validates the token.

The error "An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature" usually occurs if you are trying to validate the token which is not meant for your application.
The aud as 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 or    https://graph.microsoft.com/ are the tokens issued for Microsoft Graph.

Microsoft Graph tokens are not meant to be validated as it not meant for application.
You shouldn't try to validate the Microsoft Graph tokens as they use bit different for signing and you can't use the same methods to validate Graph API tokens.
And hence when you try to validate the Microsoft Graph token, you will get the error "Invalid signature" like below:



Hence, you must config the spring to validate the token for your aad.appScope not Microsoft Graph.

To fix this issue, you need to obtain an access token that is intended for your API backend and validate the access token.
Hence validate the token for https://acme.onmicrosoft.com/XXX" and you will not get the error.

Reference:
spring security - Verify Signature with Azure AD - Stack Overflow by juunas

so the access token from OAuth2AuthorizedClient is not for the api backend?

Yes if the aud is 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 then its not for API

so when we connect via azure with login/password, token we get is useless

Are you trying to validate Microsoft Graph API or API token?

can't say. i get ms page to enter user /password and after i get a access token in OAuth2AuthorizedClient object. I try to use this access token to access my api

What is the aud of access token in OAuth2AuthorizedClient object?
