Azure B2C IdP-Access Token fails with IDX10511: Signature validation failed
I added a working corporate login (EntraId) for my company in Azure AD B2C with custom policies.Now I can login and I add an access token to the claims, which I sent with my API-Calls Microsoft learn.
I extract this token from the claims of my b2c-iss id-token and add him in the header of my requests. As a response I get an 401 (Unauthorized) with the description:

Authentication Failed: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys
tried: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more
details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

This is the token I get:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "<some id>",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "<some id>",
  "kid": "<some id>"
}.{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  "iat": <some data>,
  "nbf": <some data>,
  "exp": <some data>,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "<some id>",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "<display name>",
  "appid": "<app id>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "<my family name>",
  "given_name": "<my given name>",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "<ip address>",
  "name": "<my name>",
  "oid": "<object id>",
  "onprem_sid": "<some id>",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "<some id>",
  "rh": "0.xy.",
  "scp": "email openid profile User.Read",
  "signin_state": [
    "inknownntwk",
    "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "<some id>",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "<tenant id>",
  "unique_name": "<email>",
  "upn": "<email>",
  "uti": "<some id>",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "<some id>"
  ],
  "xms_idrel": "1 10",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "<some id>"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": <some int>,
  "xms_tdbr": "EU"
}.[Signature]

What am I doing wrong?
I searched a lot in some forums but didn't get any answer. I'm on this error since days and can't find anything working for the specific error.

The access token with aud 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 or https://graph.microsoft.com is for Microsoft Graph API shouldn't be validated as the token is not meant for the application.

Hence do not validate the Microsoft Graph API tokens and call the API

@Rukmini thanks for your comment! But which token do I add to the request then? Any suggestions?

Which API do you want to call?

A microservice api (from my company) which is called on every request to validate the token but (as I stated) fails. I'm sorry for confusion - I'm quite new to this whole token-validation thing.

After generating the access token do you want to call Microsoft Graph Api or your custom api?

@Rukmini No, I dont't need it yet - maybe in the future.

So your goal is to just generate access token for Microsoft Graph Api scope?

Did you also checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009655/using-an-azure-ad-tenant-id-and-a-valid-token-issued-for-a-app-registration/76013867#76013867??

Not exactly - my web API'S are secured via Azure and I want to authenticate my requests - when I login as an employee of the company (and not as a regular user) I do this with my corporate login and gain an access key from this idp. And yes, I'm on it - looks like it could help me - I will try. Thanks a lot!

Can I post it as an answer?

I will try it today in the evening with my test-environment and will let you know by tomorrow. Ofc you can post it as an answer and get the credits if it works :) Thanks a lot!

Let me know if it works once resolved I will post it as an answer

You should request a token using a scope defined for your API in the Expose API page of your app registration. That way you will get an access token for your API that you can validate.

@juunas How do I enter this in my B2C then?
api://clientId/myEndpoint?

@SCH361 Check this the scope must be like this

The example shows <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>, so it would be added there, something like: <Item Key="scope">openid profile api://clientId/myEndpoint</Item>

The openid and profile scope request an ID token, which AAD B2C needs to populate claims. Adding your API scope additionally requests an access token for the API.

It must be <Item Key="scope">https://Tenant.onmicrosoft.com/XXX/Enpoint</Item> for b2c @SCH361

Seems that I get an id token with a valid access_token in it with your scope @juunas! Thanks a lot guys - really appreciate it! @Rukmini you can post your answer and i will accept it!

Note that: The access token with aud 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 or https://graph.microsoft.com is for Microsoft Graph API shouldn't be validated as the token is not meant for the application.

Microsoft Graph API tokens use a bit different for signing and you cannot use the same methods to validate Microsoft Graph API tokens.
The tokens generated for the custom API, or the application must be validated only.

I got the same error when decoded the Microsoft Graph API token:


Hence do not validate the Microsoft Graph API tokens and call the API.
Only the tokens generated for the application by exposing the API and granting permissions can be validated.

And Grant API permissions:

Generate the access token by passing scope as https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/Endpoint openid offline_access  and validate the scope like below:
<Item Key="scope">https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/XXX/Enpoint</Item>

Reference:
jwt - Using an Azure AD tenant ID - and a valid token issued for a 'app registration'. The signature verification is is failing - Stack Overflow by me
