Verify token from Microsoft Entra ID fails?
I have setup IdentityServer4 with the quickstart template to authenticate the user against Micorosft Entra ID(with FIDO2).
IdentityServer4 gets a token back and the verifikation starts in the ExternalController.Callback method. When it finnaly executes this row :
var principal = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

it fails with this exception :

IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId:
'MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs', InternalId:
'MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs'. , KeyId: MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId:
'MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs', InternalId:
'EvI8giarv1jMMohnATIJ9o5MZ_J_rThL2EGO3Upamq4'. , KeyId:
MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs '.  Number of keys in
TokenValidationParameters: '12'.  Number of keys in Configuration:
'0'.  Matched key was in 'TokenValidationParameters'.  kid:
'MGLqj10VNLoXaFfpJCBpgB4JaKs'.  Exceptions caught:  ''. token:
'RETRACTED'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10511 for details.

The KID seems to match just fine but it still fails without any explaination?
Any suggestion on how to solve this?
Authentication creation code in Program.cs :
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("Microsoft Entra ID", options =>
{
    var microsoftEntraIdSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftEntraID").Get<MicrosoftEntraIDSettings>();

    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{microsoftEntraIdSettings.TenantId}/v2.0";
    options.ClientId = microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            // Log detailed error information
            var error = context.Failure;

            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + error?.Message);
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

Here is some code from ExternalController :
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    // read external identity from the temporary cookie
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }

    var token = result.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
    var validatedToken = await ValidateTokenAsync(token);
    if (validatedToken == null)
        throw new Exception("Token validation failed");

    if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
    {
        var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
        _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
    }

    // lookup our user and external provider info
    var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
    if (user == null)
    {
        // this might be where you might initiate a custom workflow for user registration
        // in this sample we don't show how that would be done, as our sample implementation
        // simply auto-provisions new external user
        user = AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);
    }

    // this allows us to collect any additional claims or properties
    // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
    // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
    var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
    var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
    ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

    // issue authentication cookie for user
    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
    {
        DisplayName = user.Username,
        IdentityProvider = provider,
        AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);
    // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

    // retrieve return URL
    var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";
    // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

    // The client is native, so this change in how to
    // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
    if (context != null && context.IsNativeClient())
        return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}


private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateTokenAsync(string token)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    IdentityModelEventSource.LogCompleteSecurityArtifact = true;
    // Fetch the OpenID Connect configuration document
    var config = await GetOpenIdConnectConfigurationAsync();
    if (config == null || !config.SigningKeys.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("No signing keys found in configuration");
    }

    // Extract the Key ID (kid) from the token header
    var tokenKid = GetKidFromToken(token);
    _logger.LogInformation("Token kid: {TokenKid}", tokenKid);
    _logger.LogInformation("Config Signing Keys: {@Keys}", config.SigningKeys.Select(k => k.KeyId));


    // Set up token validation parameters
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_microsoftEntraIdSettings.TenantId}/v2.0",
        ValidAudiences = new[] { _microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientId },
        IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys, //config.SigningKeys, // Use all keys from the configuration
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateTokenReplay = true,
        ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
        // Additional logging for key retrieval
        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
        {
            var keys = config.SigningKeys.Where(k => k.KeyId == kid).ToList();
            _logger.LogInformation("Resolved keys for kid {Kid}: {@Keys}", kid, keys);
            return keys;
        }
    };

    try
    {
        // Validate the token using the matched public key
        var principal = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        _logger.LogInformation("Token validated successfully");
        return principal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Token validation failed");
        throw;
    }
}

private async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetOpenIdConnectConfigurationAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Fetch the OpenID Connect configuration document from Microsoft Entra ID
        var config = await _configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        _logger.LogInformation("Fetched OpenID Connect configuration: {@Config}", config);
        return config;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to fetch OpenID Connect configuration");
        throw;
    }
}

private string GetKidFromToken(string token)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    return jwtToken.Header.Kid;
}

Edit (Solved)
Apparently, I got a Microsoft Graph API token that is intended to be used with Microsoft services. This type of token should not and cannot be verified by the client. Instead, I followed @Rukmini's guide to get a proper API token that could then be verified in my Blazor app. The ValidationParameters in ExternalController.cs hade to be changed somewhat to match.
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{_microsoftEntraIdSettings.TenantId}/",
    ValidAudiences = new[] { $"api://{_microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientId}" },
    IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys, //config.SigningKeys, // Use all keys from the configuration
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateTokenReplay = true,
    ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),
    // Additional logging for key retrieval
    IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
    {
        var keys = config.SigningKeys.Where(k => k.KeyId == kid).ToList();
        _logger.LogInformation("Resolved keys for kid {Kid}: {@Keys}", kid, keys);
        return keys;
    }
};

As well as the scopes on the AddAuthentication in program.cs :
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("Microsoft Entra ID", options =>
{
    var microsoftEntraIdSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftEntraID").Get<MicrosoftEntraIDSettings>();

    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{microsoftEntraIdSettings.TenantId}/v2.0";
    options.ClientId = microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Scope.Add("api://413fef85-71c1-479a-a2b7-c7b62059a42b/BlazorToIdentityService");
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            // Log detailed error information
            var error = context.Failure;

            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + error?.Message);
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});


What is the aud of the access token? What is the scope you are passing to generate access token?

The aud is "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", the scp is "email openid profile" in the token. I have also added the creation of the authentiocation in the post above.

The access token with aud 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 or https://graph.microsoft.com is for Microsoft Graph API shouldn't be validated as the token is not meant for the application

Sorry, im somewhat new to this, but are you saying that I should not verify this token? Or do I get the wrong "kind" of token issued for something else then my user and application?

You shouldnt be validating Microsoft Graph token check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78642832/azure-b2c-idp-access-token-fails-with-idx10511-signature-validation-failed/78646437#78646437

Thanks! I am reading up and verifying settings in MS Entra ID, it obvious that I missed something in setup of Microsft Entra ID or the token request. I have created the application in Entra and i configured the OpenIdConnect with tenantId, clientID and clientSecret. Im still not sure why I get the wrong kind of token, seems to have something to do with API setup in Entra. In this case I want to verify the token, extrat userId, login(grant) the user in my blazor app and then translate the token to myToken that can be used with my API that blazer app is using. Question for another post maybe.

If you want to generate token for Microsoft Graph and call Microsoft Graph API then you can use the Graph token but it shouldnt be validated

In this case I want to use the token to login to my Blazor app as well as translate it into a token used for my API service. I will not communicate with any Microsoft produt or API more then Entra ID. So it seems like im getting the wrong type of token. How would I go about to get a the right kind of token that can ve verified against entra and then used for my application?

My problem is not really solved, but you have explained why it can't be verified, so I suppose that could be an answer to this question. Maybe I need to create another question to solve my problem. If you create an answer, I will of course grant it.

Yeah posting an answer of how you must generate token for application and validate it

Posted the answer let me know if it works

How did you setup _configurationManager?

Based on your code, you are generating access token for Microsoft Graph API:
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("profile");
options.Scope.Add("email");

And the aud is 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000, the scp is email openid profile in the token.

Note that: Only the access token meant or generated for the application must be validated.


The access token with aud 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 or https://graph.microsoft.com is for Microsoft Graph API shouldn't be validated.
Microsoft Graph API tokens use a different for signing and you cannot use the same methods to validate Microsoft Graph API tokens.
Hence, you need to generate token by passing a scope defined for your API in the Expose API blade of your app registration.
You must get an access token for your API.

When I decoded the token via for sample, even I got the same error:

If you want to generate access token for your Blazor app or your application, then check the below:
Go to your application -> Expose an API -> Add a scope

Grant API permissions for the scope you added:
Go to API permissions -> Add a permission -> APIs my organization uses -> Search you application ->Add permission

Now modify the code and pass scope as api://ClientID/ScopeName or api://ClientID/.default while generating the token.
options.Scope.Add("api://ClientID/ScopeName");

While validating the token pass audience as  ValidAudiences = new[] { _microsoftEntraIdSettings.ClientId } pass the ClientID or api://ClientID based on the token you generate.
You can refer SO Thread by me to validate token for API.

Great! i hade to change a couple of things to get it matching(see Edit) but now it works, tank you vary much!

Glad that I could help:)

@Rukmini and Banshee, i have one doubt in my case i am using nextJs for frontend with nextauth for microsoft login, and asp.net core web api for backend, As you said and i verified too that i am getting a graph token from microsoft after login, how can i create access token then, as in frontend its not secure to create token because anyone can inspect element and see the client secret
