Verify Microsoft Access token on my ASP.NET Core Web API
On my client side (nextAuth) I am getting an access token once from Microsoft, now I want that token to be verified from backend which is on ASP.NET Core Web API. As far as I know the process is to get the keys from Microsoft and the one which has same "kid" use that to verify.
This is the header part of my JWT that I got from Microsoft:
{
    "nonce": "v9eWI-Nv75YgvN8IgSNSlHPK-UH8iOcEUz8KXqj6DeA",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "x5t": "H9nj5AOSswMphg1SFx7jaV-lB9w",
    "kid": "H9nj5AOSswMphg1SFx7jaV-lB9w"
}

Now after lots of trying I was forced to hardcode certificate value of key that I got from Microsoft to get some success
I visited the URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantId}/discovery/keys?appid={clientId}
And got this
{
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "H9nj5AOSswMphg1SFx7jaV-lB9w",
      "x5t": "H9nj5AOSswMphg1SFx7jaV-lB9w",
      "n": "iheTlbqieo0KzaFBTz6dxt9LAENfe2d0ywnpvZx9khzurtApc4ThWBpeoTBI6UpReeCwyW6DQjJSGCqHwe-wqRdgoiMc0PV-danrh0px38x2KL_j7VoHR0hlQBYOpp5GBMdz-Nsc80wBtHAqxz7Nno3qYNTXUvwZ2LSbbvgoPXrh0zhLlSrn2gAroRv6Z8xSOVg3CSmZeVgZHJv4aMYQiBiIIZW68YN5ywHxOf6-LdrhqN24NPSLYUNPKGxCkUkWg-VV-iulUqIkDxn3SKiX4zVA-jevbuUrsK3MeRHoJLqXMf8KnpPkf4ZLCTLdUNFyLyxFvqnm6QUAgpDrQ_rxhw",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "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"
      ]
    }

As you can see both have same kid.
This is my backend code:
 private const string KeyString = @"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";

 [HttpPost("validate-token3")]
 public IActionResult DecodeValidToken()
 {
     try
     {
         string accessToken = "MyTokenHereWhichICannotPasteHere";

         var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString));
         var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
         var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
         var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

         var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = rsaSecurityKey,
             ValidateIssuer = false,
             ValidateAudience = false
         };

         var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
         return Ok(principal.Claims);
     }
     catch (SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException ex)
     {
         return Unauthorized(new { Message = "Invalid token signature", Details = ex.Message });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "Internal server error", Details = ex.Message });
     }
 }

Even though my token has kid still I am getting this error:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: 'IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'y16ADo8cPNxOAHfa262kqg7euKagSoVzzY5Wo4CzT5c'. , KeyId:
'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Exceptions caught:
''.
token: '[Security Artifact of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/SecurityArtifactLogging.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.'

I am trying to solve this issue from last 4 days, but still no luck yet, even I have tried a different approach in which we are getting keys from Microsoft and passing all the keys to validate

Is there any chance you can share one of the access tokens (can be depreciated) so I can look into it?

What is there aud of the access token can you decode the token and attach the snip?

hi @Rukmini it's 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

But you mentioned here that the aud is Microsoft Graph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78724986/verify-token-from-microsoft-entra-id-fails/78725378?noredirect=1#comment139279286_78725378

@CodeNoob Can you decode the access token in jwt.ms and paste the screenshot?

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78408841/how-to-validate-entra-validation-token-on-api

ok, i am editing the question here and pasting the Screenshot @Rukmini

@CodeNoob You are trying to validate Microsoft Graph API access token and so you are getting the error

The Microsoft Graph API tokens are not meant to be validated

@Rukmini ok, then can you please help me, as i am using nextauth for micrsoft login and getting this token, then how can i verify this in my backend ? also if i get a access token using the end point by following the steps you created by exposing an api , then anyone from my front end can inspect element and get the secret keys

Where are you generating the access token now?

As my microsoft login logic is on frontend, then i have to generate the token in front end only (but its not a secure way ), and in backend i can't generate as there is not way to verify if the request is legit or not

I dont feel that might cause a issue

Here you can see that access token is generated in Frontend https://medium.com/sopra-steria-norge/how-to-acquire-and-use-an-access-token-from-azure-ad-in-a-react-spring-app-a-simple-developers-fceffa1b7893

And check this too https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/5996

@Rukmini ok let me check, also thanks a lot for instant replies you have great skills , great to have people like you

I generated access token and tried to validate the token using the same code as below:

Got the same error:


Note that: Microsoft Graph API tokens are not meant to be validated.


It is intended to be used with Microsoft services.
You can only validate the APIs that are meant to for your application.

Hence to resolve the error, check the below:
Expose an API and add a scope:

Grant API permission:

Make sure to generate access token by passing scope as api://***/ScopeName
Now the token is valid and got the output successfully:
class Program
{
    private const string KeyString = @"xxx";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accessToken = "MyTokenHereWhichICannotPasteHere"; 

        try
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString));
            var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
            var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = rsaSecurityKey,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };

            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
            Console.WriteLine("Token is valid. Claims:");
            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unauthorized: Invalid token signature. Details: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}


Refer this GitHub blog Azure AD Authentication, Next-Auth JWT and .NET Core Web API · nextauthjs/next-auth · Discussion #5996 · GitHub where the access token is generated in the frontend using Next-Auth.
