# Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter Error Logs in AzureAD Auth Implementation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have integrated AzureAD for our API Authorization and API Auth is working fine but seeing error logs for Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter with below messages,

**IDX40003: Neither `tid` nor `tenantId` claim is present in the token obtained from Microsoft identity platform.**

**IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid: '***'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '16'. Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. Exceptions caught: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Valid Lifetime: 'False'. Valid Issuer: 'False'**

Our APIs are being consumed by UI APP as well as via Swagger/Postman.

What should be root cause to it?

Comment: Could you provide the endpoint you are using to get the access token. Are you able to decode the token using https://www.jwt.ms ?

Comment: @ShwetaM, I am generating token from AzureAD endpoint and yes able to generate the token from jwt.ms.

Answer (score 0):

The error `IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid` occurs when the Kid in your decoded token which validates token signature is not valid.
So one needs to load keys from the openid provider.

**code:**

```
var openidConfiguration = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
                new HttpDocumentRetriever());
            var config = await openidConfiguration.GetConfigurationAsync();

            var parameteres = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireAudience = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAudiences = new[] { "<my client id or appId uri or resource identitifer>" },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/" }, 
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys
            };
```

- AppId Uri , you can check from the portal : api://

[image]

Add the  following to check for more clear descriptive exception in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` :`IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true`

*Example:*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
                     ...
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
                       ...
             }
```

**Reference :** [Azure AD - Why can't I validate JWT token issued by Azure AD for my Web API? Getting "IDX10516: Signature validation failed" error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554056/azure-ad-why-cant-i-validate-jwt-token-issued-by-azure-ad-for-my-web-api-get)

Comment: How about error, IDX40003: Neither tid nor tenantId claim is present in the token obtained from Microsoft identity platform. This error is showing up even when token has tid claim present.